# Linq-To-Sql / comma separated Ids in 1 column / return comma separated Names in 1 column

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I have an entity with several columns except for 1 column that stores a comma separated Ids.

When I return data to client, I need to query some other table to return Name instead of Id.

I am using Linq-To-Sql. The query does Left Outer Joins to many other tables, but still not sure how to go about this property that should be kept as 1 column but names rather than Ids.

```
 var query = (
from poc in _manager.All
    // Shelter
    join s in _shelters.GetAll() on poc.Shelter equals s.Id into JoinShelter
    from sh in JoinShelter.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new Dto
        {
            Id = poc.Id,
            PocPresent = poc.PocPresent ? "Yes" : "No",
            Shelter = sh.ShelterName
        }
```

There is still 1 property called Languages. It is a string of "1,2" meaning Language 1 and Language 2.

On the "poc" the property is Languages = "1,2"

Now, I need to return it as "Lang1, Lang2".

How's it doable with Lin-To-Sql?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use projection on `Languages` property, with `Select()` LINQ extension method.

```
var query = (
  from poc in _manager.All
  // Shelter
  join s in _shelters.GetAll() on poc.Shelter equals s.Id into JoinShelter
  from sh in JoinShelter.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new Dto
  {
    Id = poc.Id,
    PocPresent = poc.PocPresent ? "Yes" : "No",
    Shelter = sh.ShelterName,
    Languages = poc.Languages.Split(",".ToCharArray()).Select(l => "Lang"+l)
  })
```

In this example `Languages` property on `Dto` object will be `IEnumerable<string>`. If you need it back in csv string formati, you can do it via `String.Join` method.

Comment: Thanks. But I have a long query where I am not executing it until I am done from my query building. Will the code above run while inside the query? If no, then if I use String.Join it will run on the spot right?

Comment: Yes you are right, `Languages` projection will not be made on a database directly. It will be made in server's memory instead. Maybe you should focus on getting right subset from your database, and then you can make similar in-memory transformations in order to display desired data.

Comment: I tried the above, in my case it is not as simple as "Lang"+1, I have to query another tables to get names from the ids. So, my property would be something as IEnumerable<IQueryable<string>>. 

In-memory is not an option as I have many records returned so I thought I would shift all complexities onto SQL Server.

Comment: If that's the case, you should try to split `Languages` by delimiter and then use inner query to get proper names by each id from that list.